# move: The filename or extension is too long

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a small script in a bat file that I use to create backups of a folder on my computer:

```
rmdir "Folder - Backup (Old)" /S /Q
move "Folder - Backup" "Folder - Backup (Old)"
mkdir "Folder - Backup"
xcopy /e /h "Folder"\*.* "Folder - Backup"
```

I recently moved "Folder" along with the backup script into a new directory and now the script isn't working:

```
move "Folder - Backup" "Folder - Backup (Old)"
The filename or extension is too long.
        0 dir(s) moved.
```

I'm guessing this is caused by the full file path of `Folder` being too long, but I don't have this problem when I rename the folder using Windows Explorer so it's not like this operation isn't possible in Windows. Is there a work-around for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `move` to do a rename is overkill. Try

```
ren "Folder - Backup" "Folder - Backup (Old)"
```

Comment: REN doesn't work on folders. you'll get a very vague 'The syntax of the command is incorrect' error

Comment: @georgiecasey The cases where `ren` does not work are a) Can only have exactly two arguments b) Second argument can only be a file name, not a path or drive c) First argument cannot be a wildcard to rename a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell's move-item instead of move.

This works especially well if you actually need to move something (vs doing a rename).

`powershell move-item 'Folder - Backup' 'Folder - Backup (Old)'`