# Batch Script: Move Folder & Contents to New Path

Tags: batch-file, directory

### Problem

I'm trying to move a folder (ex. `\\myUNC\folder1`) and its contents to another folder (ex. `\\myUNC\Parent\folder1`). There are two easy enough ways I'd typically do this - either using `move` (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470880/move-folder-from-one-directory-to-another-in-batch-script)) or using `ren` (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057104/move-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long)).

### Example Code

```
set oldPath=\\myUNC\folder1
set newPath=\\myUNC\Parent\folder1
move "%oldPath%" "%newPath%"
::ren"%oldPath%" "%newPath%"
```

### Troubleshooting

When attempting the `move` solution in my first like, I get the error:

> The filename or extension is too long. 0 dir(s) moved.

As a result, I tried `ren` like in my second link, which gave the error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

For this second error, I'm assuming that is because I'm passing the path as part of my variable - which `ren` doesn't accept. **The batch calling this change is NOT in the same directory** as the folder or its new path. As a result I can't use current directory code (like `ren` or `cd`), at least as far as I know.

If anyone has a possible solution it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `ren` or `rename` just does what it says: renaming files; so you cannot use it for moving files... anyway, try with [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting, I was able to find a solution with no errors!

### Solution

```
set oldPath=\\myUNC\folder1
set newPath=\\myUNC\Parent\folder1
robocopy /move "%oldPath%" "%newPath%"
```

### Why

`Robocopy` is a newer command from Microsoft, and accounts for filename strings longer than 256 characters (apparently the issue with `move` and/or `copy` command).

You can google robocopy to learn more about the command options and parameters, but its fairly straight forward. For my issue, I wanted to move the file, so I just used the `/move` option, which deletes the original folder and files.

Answer (score 1):

> The filename or extension is too long. 0 dir(s) moved.

This error refers to a 'feature' in Windows that limits file names to a maximum of 255 characters. To overcome this, you would need to **shorten the names of the folders on the Network drive**. 
See [Maximum filename length in NTFS (Windows XP and Windows Vista)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

This error occured because you cannot state a new folder for the `ren` command. A file can only be renamed in the same folder, not even subdirectories are allowed. But the reason why you got `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` error, is because you left out a space in between the `ren` and the `"`

## Possible solution:

Depending on your scenario, you might be able to `pushd` into the folder and then use the move command. In my experience, some commands don't respond equally to UNC locations vs local file locations (ex. `if exist "\\UNC\"`):

```
@echo off
pushd \\myUNC\
set oldPath=folder1
set newPath=Parent\folder1
move "%oldPath%" "%newPath%"
popd
```

This will only work though, if you haven't exceeded the 255 char limit

Comment: Unfortunately the pushd solution didn't work. I've found an alternative solution using `robocopy` however.